# Redirecionamento form javascript

Tags: javascript, formulário

Tenho esse código JS que faz validação, envia e salva no BD os arquivos do form.
Preciso que depois de enviar e salvar no bd, após o alert, o usuário sejá redirecionado para outra página.

```
<script>
      var form = document.getElementById("myform");

      form.onsubmit = function (e) {

          // stop the regular form submission
          e.preventDefault();

          // collect the form data while iterating over the inputs
          var data = {};

          var error = 0;
          var serror = 0;

          for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
              var input = form[i];
              if (input.name) {
                  if (input.name == "gender") {
                      if ($('input[name=gender]:checked').length > 0)
                          data[input.name] = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
                      else {
                          error++;

                          if (serror == 0) {
                              alert('Selecione o sexo');
                              serror++;
                          }
                      }
                  } else {
                      if (input.name == "name") {
                          if (input.value.length >= 3 && input.value != "Nome")
                              data[input.name] = input.value;
                          else {
                              error++;
                              alert('Nome inválido');
                          }
                      } else if (input.name == "email") {
                          var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
                          if (re.test(input.value))
                              data[input.name] = input.value;
                          else {
                              error++;
                              alert('E-mail inválido');
                          }

                      } else if (input.name == "extra") {
                          if (input.value.length >= 3 && input.value != "extra")
                              data[input.name] = input.value;
                          else {
                              error++;
                              alert('Campo inválido');
                          }                        

                      } else if (input.name == "source") {
                          data[input.name] = input.value;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          if (error <= 0){
              addData(data);
          } else {
              error = 0;
          }
      }

      function addData(data){
          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "...",
               data: JSON.stringify(data),
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               crossDomain: true,
               dataType: "json",
               beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                   xhr.setRequestHeader ("", "");
               },

               success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                   alert("Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!");
                   form.reset();
               },

               error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                   // error handler
                   console.log(jqXHR);
                   alert('Houve um erro ao tentar realizar seu cadastro.' + status.code);
               }
          });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: porque não usa: window.location.href = 'linkOuNomeDaPagina"  depois do alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim logo depois do alert():

```
window.location = "pagina-de-retorno";
```